# Update Multiple Columns in One Statement Based On a Field with the Same Value as the Column Name

Tags: t-sql

Not sure if this is possible without some sort of Dynamic SQL or a Pivot (which I want to stay away from)... I have a report that displays total counts for various types/ various status combinations... These types and statuses are always going to be the same and present on the report, so returning no data for a specific combination yields a zero. As of right now there are only three caseTypes (Vegetation, BOA, and Zoning) and 8 statusTypes (see below).

I am first setting up the skeleton of the report using a temp table. I have been careful to name the temp table columns the same as what the "statusType" column will contain in my second table "#ReportData". Is there a way to update the different columns in "#FormattedData" based on the value of the "statusType" column in my second table?

*Creation of Formatted Table (for report):*

```
CREATE TABLE #FormattedReport (
    caseType                VARCHAR(50)
    , underInvestigation    INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    , closed                INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    , closedDPW             INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    , unsubtantiated        INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    , currentlyMonitored    INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    , judicialProceedings   INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    , pendingCourtAction    INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    , other                 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)

INSERT INTO #FormattedReport (caseType) VALUES ('Vegetation')
INSERT INTO #FormattedReport (caseType) VALUES ('BOA')
INSERT INTO #FormattedReport (caseType) VALUES ('Zoning')
```

*Creation of Data Table (to populate #FormattedReport):*

```
SELECT B.Name AS caseType, C.Name AS StatusType, COUNT(*) AS Amount
INTO #ReportData
FROM table1 A
   INNER JOIN table2 B ...
   INNER JOIN table3 C ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY B.Name, C.Name
```

*CURRENT Update Statement (Currently will be 1 update per column in #FormattedReport):*

```
UPDATE A SET underInvestigation = Amount FROM #ReportData B
    INNER JOIN #FormattedReport A ON B.CaseType LIKE CONCAT('%', A.caseType, '%')
    WHERE B.StatusType = 'Under Investigation'
UPDATE A SET closed = Amount FROM #ReportData B
    INNER JOIN #FormattedReport A ON B.CaseType LIKE CONCAT('%', A.caseType, '%')
    WHERE B.StatusType = 'Closed'
...
```

**REQUESTED Update Statement: Would like to have ONE update statement knowing which column to update when "#ReportData.statusType" is the same as a "#FormattedData" column's name. For my "other" column, I'll just do that one manually using a NOT IN.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question, I think you can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CaseType
           ,SUM(CASE WHEN StatusType = 'Under Investigation' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) As underInvestigation
           ,SUM(CASE WHEN StatusType = 'Closed' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) As closed
           -- ... More of the same 
    FROM #ReportData
    GROUP BY CaseType
)

UPDATE A 
SET underInvestigation = B.underInvestigation
    ,closed = b.closed
    -- more of the same 
FROM #FormattedReport A 
INNER JOIN CTE B
    ON B.CaseType LIKE CONCAT('%', A.caseType, '%')
```

Comment: This worked (with some tweaks), thank you! I had to change MAX() to SUM() and also add in "ELSE 0" to every CASE statement or else it would error out for trying to insert a NULL. All in all this ended up only saving me about 10 lines of code but it looks much cleaner and I learned something today. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help :-) I'll edit the answer to reflect those changes.

Comment: I went back in and stripped down everything after seeing how your CTE worked. I removed the entire formatted table all together and just used 2 selects. One for the "#ReportData" initial data, and then your CTE without the wrapping to get the final result. Went from about 70 lines to 28. Again, I appreciate the help, I have a much much cleaner procedure now.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help :-)